# Execute a query returned from a scalar function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scalar function that returns a query. The scalar function must return the query itself and not its' results, since it uses dynamic SQL and the variables are used as column names and table names.

So, I have something like this:

```
SELECT  t.id, 
        dbo.queryToExecute(t.id, t.ColumnToFetch, t.TableToFetchFrom) QueryToExecute 
FROM Table t
```

Which returns

```
| ID | QueryToExecute
| 1  | SELECT ColumnName1 FROM Table1 WHERE id = 1
| 2  | SELECT ColumnName2 FROM Table2 WHERE id = 2
```

While "QueryToExecute" returns a single value.
I want to do something like:

```
SELECT  t.id, 
        EXEC(dbo.queryToExecute(t.id, t.ColumnToFetch, t.TableToFetchFrom)) ExecutedQuery 
FROM Table t
```

So the result set will be:

```
| ID | ExecutedQuery
| 1  | Jacob
| 2  | Sarah
```

How can I do that?

I already have a stored procedure that gets the job done when I need to run individually, but I wanted to have the same thing on a scalar function in order to be able to embed the sub-results in more complex queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL:

```
DECALRE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @sql = COALESCE(@sql,'') + 
            REPLACE(
                dbo.queryToExecute(t.id, t.ColumnToFetch, t.TableToFetchFrom),
                'SELECT ',
                'SELECT '+ CAST(t.ID as nvarchar(max) +' as ID, '
                ) +' UNION ALL ' 
FROM Table t

SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql)-LEN('UNION ALL '))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

This will get all query's in one batch and execute it

Comment: I have 2 issues with this: 1. I want to get the executed query along with the id (another column). 2. Now I get a result set for each row in the table. I want to get a single result set with all of the id's and their executed queries.

Comment: Show resultset you need please

Comment: I edited the question with the desired output, thanks

Comment: OK, cool. I had to make some minor changes but it works! also, my query contained a subselect, so I had to replace the "REPLACE" with STUFF: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/586f63d1-866a-4547-ad19-37096d5d8eb7/how-to-replace-first-occurrence-of-word-in-tsql?forum=transactsql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take your dynamic sql one step deeper, and include the id number.

This script will generate a select statement for each row, and union them all together. You then run this whole select in one go to get your output.

```
--set up a string variable to store your query
declare @tsql nvarchar(max);
set @tsql = '';

-- populate it with the string statements
select @tsql = @tsql + 'select ' + cast(t.id as nvarchar(10)) + ' as id , (' + dbo.queryToExecute(t.id, t.ColumnToFetch, t.TableToFetchFrom) + ') QueryToExecute union ' from Table t

--chop off the final "union"
select @tsql = left (@tsql,len(@tsql)-7);

--and run
EXEC sp_executesql @tsql
```